# Default root object in AWS CDN url from multiple s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url, default, cdn

How do i default root objects in multiple aws cdn buckets.
lets say for bucket S1 : abcd.cloudfront.net opens index1.html by default
and   for bucket S2:   abcd.cludfront.net/folder opens index2.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Root object is specified at Distribution level, not behaviors nor cache levels.  From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html):

> Remember that a default **root object applies only to your CloudFront distribution**.

Probably you could use [cloud functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html) or lambda@edge to modify the requests to your origins.